# SQL rolling sum for each date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below SQL Query that is used to produce a report for trade data based on the user's input. The user selects the start date and end date for the report and generates the report.  Where the variables normally are, I have entered the dates 2018-05-01 and 2018-05-06 for easier reference.

Here are the basics of the table used in this query as well as the two rows used in the sample.

```
create table activity (
Act_ID int(11),
ACT_QTY int(11),
ACT_PRICE decimal(8,5),
ACT_TRADE_DT date,
ACT_SETTLE_DT date, 
ACT_EXTND_SETT varchar(1),
ACT_HOLD_STATUS varchar(140)
);

INSERT INTO activity (ACT_QTY, ACT_PRICE, ACT_TRADE_DT, ACT_SETTLE_DT, 
ACT_EXTND_SETT )
VALUES ('10', '103.33', '2018-04-25', '2018-05-02', 'Y'), 
('5', '103.40', '2018-04-26', '2018-05-04', 'Y');
```

Here's the query that is working.

```
SELECT date_query.date_range AS 'Date', 
CASE WHEN a.sum_qty is NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.sum_qty END AS 'QTY Sum', 
CASE WHEN a.Total_Dollar is NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.Total_Dollar END AS 'Total 
Dollar', 
CASE WHEN a.Total_Cap_Cost is NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.Total_Cap_Cost END AS 'Total Capital Used' 
FROM
  (
  select sub.date_range from 
    (select adddate('2001-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0) 
date_range from
    (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    (select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    (select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
    (select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) sub
    where date_range between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-06'
  ) date_query
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
      SELECT ACT_SETTLE_DT, sum( ACT_QTY ) AS 'Sum_QTY', round((ACT_PRICE * 
ACT_QTY * 10), 2) AS Total_Dollar, round((ACT_PRICE * ACT_QTY * 10 * .07),2) 
AS Total_Cap_Cost FROM activity WHERE ACT_EXTND_SETT = 'Y' AND ACT_HOLD_STATUS != 
'Cancelled' GROUP BY ACT_SETTLE_DT
    ) a
ON date_query.date_range = a.act_settle_dt
ORDER BY date_query.date_range ASC
```

The current output looks like this:

```
2018-05-01 | 0   | 0        | 0
2018-05-02 | 10  |10333.00  | 723.31
2018-05-03 | 0   | 0        | 0
2018-05-04 | 5   | 5170.00  | 361.90
2018-05-05 | 0   | 0        | 0
2018-05-06 | 0   | 0        | 0
```

Here's where I'm struggling.

I'm attempting to adapt the current query to achieve a rolling sum for each of the columns when the act_settle_dt is less than date_query.date_range.  Instead of sum(act_qty) for each date, I need something to the affect of sum(act_qty) where act_settle_date < date_query.date_range.

The new output should look something like this:

```
2018-05-01 | 15  | 15503.00 | 1085.21
2018-05-02 | 15  | 15503.00 | 1085.21
2018-05-03 | 5   | 5170.00  | 361.90
2018-05-04 | 5   | 5170.00  | 361.90
2018-05-05 | 0   | 0        | 0
2018-05-06 | 0   | 0        | 0
```

I need to be able to show the exposure of a user-selected time period to the quantity and dollar amount of each trade that hasn't settled yet.

The server is on MySQL 5.6 so using something like an OVER clause isn't an option.  I've attempted several things such as to include a case clause in the sum but to no avail.  I'm no expert in SQL as is probably evident by my patchwork query, any guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks

***UPDATE:*** 
I have narrowed the SQL down to the following.

```
SELECT date_query.date_range AS 'Date', 
CASE WHEN a.sum_qty is NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.sum_qty END AS 'Ext Trade Qty', 
CASE WHEN a.Total_Dollar is NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.Total_Dollar END AS 'Total 
Dollar', 
CASE WHEN a.Total_Cap_Cost is NULL THEN 0 ELSE a.Total_Cap_Cost END AS 'Total 
Capital Used',
```

> SUM(CASE WHEN a.ACT_SETTLE_DT > date_query.date_range THEN a.sum_qty ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Cumulative Ext Qty'

```
FROM
  (
  select sub.date_range from 
    (select adddate('2001-01-01',t4*10000 + t3*1000 + t2*100 + t1*10 + t0)         
date_range from
    (select 0 t0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4     
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (select 0 t1 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
(select 0 t2 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 
union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
(select 0 t3 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
(select 0 t4 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) sub
    where date_range between '2018-05-01' and '2018-05-06'
  ) date_query
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT ACT_TRADE_DT, ACT_SETTLE_DT, sum( ACT_QTY ) AS 'Sum_QTY', 
sum(round((ACT_PRICE * ACT_QTY * 10), 2)) AS Total_Dollar, 
sum(round((ACT_PRICE * ACT_QTY * 10 * .07),2)) AS Total_Cap_Cost 
  FROM activity WHERE ACT_EXTND_SETT = 'Y' AND ACT_TRADE_DT <= '2018-05-06' 
AND ACT_SETTLE_DT > '2018-05-01'
  GROUP BY ACT_SETTLE_DT
) a
ON date_query.date_range = a.act_settle_dt
GROUP BY date_query.date_range
ORDER BY date_query.date_range ASC
```

Can someone explain why the blocked CASE WHEN isn't working as intended?

I am trying to compare the settlement dates to the current date of the row. I want to get a sum of all rows up to the current row's date. In this updated code, I get a 0 value for the cumulative column for all rows. Can anyone explain why the case when is not picking up the values when doing the date comparison? 
 Or am I going about this in entirely the wrong way?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry - Thanks for the feedback.  I realize this is probably a simple query, but I'm not a programmer and am looking for assistance where I can.

Comment: Hence the comment above.

Comment: I have added the create/insert data.  My question already has the working query, the desired outcome set, and a reference to my failed attempts, although not written out in code form.  I'm not sure how much more I can provide.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: You could provide a data set that aligned with the result set I guess.

Comment: I added that in the edit.  I have the basics of the table as well as the data set for the two rows used in the example.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error I abandoned the CASE method.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN a.ACT_SETTLE_DT > date_query.date_range THEN a.sum_qty ELSE 0 END ) AS 'Cumulative Ext Qty'
```

I was finally able to come to an answer using a sub query comparing the dates inside a WHERE clause.  Seems simple enough, and I figured it would be.  If anyone has a cleaner/simpler option, feel free to post.

```
(SELECT SUM(ACT_QTY)
    FROM activity A2
    where A2.ACT_TRADE_DT <= date_query.date_range and
          A2.ACT_SETTLE_DT >= date_query.date_range
   ) as 'Cumulative Sum',
(SELECT SUM(round((ACT_PRICE * ACT_QTY * 10), 2))
    FROM activity A2
    where A2.ACT_TRADE_DT <= date_query.date_range and
          A2.ACT_SETTLE_DT >= date_query.date_range
   ) as 'Cumulative Total Dollar',
(SELECT SUM(round((ACT_PRICE * ACT_QTY * 10 * .07),2))
    FROM activity A2
    where A2.ACT_TRADE_DT <= date_query.date_range and
          A2.ACT_SETTLE_DT >= date_query.date_range
   ) as 'Cumululative Cap Total'
```

The result set shows as intended.

```
2018-05-01 | 15  | 15503.00 | 1085.21
2018-05-02 | 15  | 15503.00 | 1085.21
2018-05-03 | 5   | 5170.00  | 361.90
2018-05-04 | 5   | 5170.00  | 361.90
2018-05-05 | 0   | 0        | 0
2018-05-06 | 0   | 0        | 0
```